# What is the appropriate way to dynamically load a png image from file into a Timage on a Tpanel, thereafter resizing/ zooming/ panning it?

Tags: image, delphi, image-resizing

I do a `LoadFromFile()` for a PNG image into a `Timage` that is on a `TPanel` on a Form. The Form's `OnCreate` event maximizes the Form, and the Panel is set to `alClient` so it resizes nicely. But the PNG image does not, it only fills to the `TPanel`'s design-time dimensions. And it looks horribly low resolution, no matter how hi-res the source image is.

I get it to resize in an `OnClick` event by using `Image.SetBound()`, but it does not look good.

I have also tried with a BMP and JPG, but without success.

I am guessing there is something fundamental I do not understand, but I cannot find the 'recipe' for this anywhere.

Comment: VCL or FMX? What are the exact property settings of the `TImage`?

Comment: If you have a `TImage` on a `TPanel`, then you should make sure that *both* the image *and* the panel have `Align = alClient`. Also, the `TImage` should (of course) have `Stretch = True` (and `Proportional = True`).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand gave the correct design. Also make sure you have an image big enough for the entire screen and same width/height ratio the TImage when resized). If ratio is not the same, the image will be stretched more in a direction that the other. In that case, you should not use Align = client for TImage but instead set the width/height ratio the same as the image ratio and fit either the TImage in the panel's width or height, adjust the other dimension to get the correct ratio and set the left/top properties to center (or whatever) the TImage inside the panel OnResize event handler.

Comment: I made all of this and more in an open source application available from https://github.com/fpiette/OvbImgOrganizer

Comment: Using VCL. Have tried all sort of property settings to no avail. To be able to zoom, and pan the image using scrollbars, the image must be allowed to be larger than the panel. This puts restrictions to using align and autosize properties. I tried an alternativ solution: putting the image directly onto the form instead of on a panel on the form - and it works. Maybe it is something about the signalling form->panel->image?

Comment: If you need to zoom and pan the image, you cannot use a simple `TImage`. In fact, there are no built-in VCL facilities for this. Instead, you need to create your own custom control. Personally, I have created a `TImageViewer` control that supports zooming and panning.

Comment: Putting the Timage directly on the form I am able to zoom by using SetBound , and pan by modifying Timage.Left and Top properties. Negative Left and Top values are accepted. I use Radio to do zoom, and Scrollbars to do pan. When I try the same but on a panel on the form, I get into trouble.

Comment: Yes, you can do a primitive form of zoom and pan using those methods. But in a user-friendly app, the user should be able to pan by dragging the mouse and zoom by using the mouse wheel (optionally this should zoom in and out to/from the current cursor position). And then you "need" a custom (reusable!) control. But again, your simplified version should be possible to implement out of the box. Still, this Q doesn't quite focus on any particular, well-descirbed problem.

Comment: @fpiette:  Your OvbImageOrganizer is a very nice piece of work,

Comment: @Erlend you should really look into OvbImgOrganizer, the open source I pointed you in previous comment. Specifically, look at OvbImgOrganizer.SlideShow.pas which is a superset of Window 7 image viewer. It zoom in/out pan/flip/rotate images. The code is to long to publish as an answer. That source file is there: https://github.com/fpiette/OvbImgOrganizer/blob/main/Source/OvbImgOrganizer.SlideShow.pas

Comment: Thanks, I will explore OvbImgOrganizer.SlideShow, I have gone and picked up the source. Thank you both.